# Why the mentioned code is undefined behaviour in C

Tags: c, c99

The statement `a[i]=i++;` is undefined as there is a confusion that which value of `i`(old or new) to use to evaluate the left side to get the `L-value`. This compiler gives a warning (operation .. may be undefined) for this statement if compiled with `-Wall`.

In the code below , in the statement `x->a = x->b, ++x++->b;`
`x` is being changed and in the left side it is used to get the `L-value`. For this statement, compiler does not give any warning if executed with `-Wall`.

Could someone please explain why this is not undefined behaviour?
Thanks!

```
struct Data {
int a;
int b;
} y[4] = { 10, 20, 30, 40};

struct Data *x = y;
int i;

for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
    x->a = x->b, ++x++->b;
    printf("%d %d\t", y[i].a, y[i].b);
}
```

Comment: Just because the compiler didn't warn, doesn't mean that the behaviour really is well defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comma operator has the lowest precedence,

> *expression:*
>   *assignment-expression*
>   *expression `,` assignment-expression*

so

```
x->a = x->b, ++x++->b;
```

is actually

```
(x->a = x->b), ++(x++->b);
```

and the comma operator is a sequence point, thus the two modifications to `x` are sequenced, and there is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: right, I missed that.  It will be undefined if the statement        x->a = ++x++->b; thanks

Answer (score 7):

`x->a = x->b, ++x++->b;` does not invoke undefined behavior. The comma operator has lower precedence than the assignment operator, so this code is equivalent to:

```
x->a = x->b;
++x++->b;
```

In the second line there, the postfix `++` operator is modifying `x`, and the prefix `++` operator is modifying the member `b` of the dereferenced structure. No sequence point rules are being violated.

Comment: Proof that being well-defined and being clear aren't necessarily the same thing.